# Change command-line arguments for favorite applications in Dock

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I've added an option to Exec line in `.desktop` file for GNOME Terminal (I need to add `--maximize`). File is `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`.

I have Terminal in my favorites in Dock. But my changes has no effects - terminal still launches in a normal mode, even after restarting GNOME shell. Where is the problem and how can I change command line arguments for my favorites applications in Dock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on Terminal icon on Dock, actually ***New Window*** action is performed. I believe you added `--maximize` flag only in main entries which will give you *maximized* terminal window when launched from launcher. So, edit the `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and add the above said flag to ***New Window*** also. It would look like:

```
[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=gnome-terminal --window --maximize
```